# ObjectParameter in the System.Data.Objects namespace with international characters

Tags: .net

I'm trying to use ObjectParameter in the System.Data.Objects namespace.

This one does work: new ObjectParameter("test", 1)
This one throws an error: new ObjectParameter("täst", 1)

The problem is when the first parameter includes Swedish characters like å, ä, ö. I get the following error message: The specified parameter name 'täst' is not valid. Parameter names must begin with a letter and can only contain letters, numbers, and underscores. Parameter name: name

Why doesn’t this work? It seems strange if international characters are not supported!

/S

Answer (score 1):

It doesn't seem *terribly* strange to me. After all, this is the *name* of a parameter - it's not like it's the *value* of the parameter.

It's just like the fact that variable names, method names etc can't contain non-ASCII characters in some languages (I've just checked and it turns out they *can* in C#...).

For the sake of simplicity in terms of getting things right, I'd generally recommend that table names, stored procedure names, parameter names etc are better off in ASCII anyway. I realise this is very Anglo-Saxon-biased, but given how bad we are as an industry at getting Unicode etc right in general, creating easily-misused names for *identifiers* seems like a recipe for disaster to me. In particular, equality among ASCII characters is pretty straightforward - it can be case-sensitive or case-insensitive, but that's about. There are no culture-specific issues to worry about.

When you've got the whole range of Unicode letters to worry about, you may end up matching different names when using different cultures... and surely that's not a good idea.

I agree that the documentation could be a *lot* clearer though :)